# Drupal date range indexing with Apache Solr

Tags: date, drupal, solr, lucene, field

i am using these drupal modules

```
search_api 
search_api_solr
date_range_formatter 
views
```

and in fact many other modules to get my Solr / Drupal project going to index ~100000 nodes of content.

The setup is working great, BUT i need to get search results from the Solr for a date range field and this is where i am stuck.

Somehow i am stuck with setting up the correct operator "between" and "not between" and using "<=" or ">=" is causing trouble here.

I can't get my Solr-query like

```
field[1 TO *] AND field[* TO 10]
```

to work.

One content type can have multiple date ranges when available for searching.

The user **can search for a start date and an end date**. The daterange should match inside each individual daterange of the indexed entity type.

Let's say it is valid from:

```
2015-10-01 to 2015-10-10
2015-11-01 to 2015-11-10
...
```

and so on.

To get me going and sort the problems the right way i need to know first:

What is the best practise to store a date range inside Drupal to index at the Solr side? Is a date range a good way or would is better to store a range with a value for each day individually like:

```
2015-10-01
2015-10-02
2015-10-03
...
```

What is the best for Solr to index a date range?

What field type inside Drupal would you suggest to store the values inside an entity type to be able to send it to Drupal?

I know i am not the first struggeling with this. Details can be found here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1783746

but onfortunately none of these patches were error free to my setup. I tried all out to get this going. Now i am looking for any advice, sum ups or thoughts that might be helpful to track down my last bits of errors.

Any advice or idea is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a step by step solution. I just want to give you an idea how to adapt this to your project and still stay compatible with *search_api* and *search_api_solr*:

One possible solution could be to store and index the dates from an entity in one field per date individually as

```
2015-10-01
2015-10-02
2015-10-03
...
```

after this use

```
function mymodule_search_api_views_query_alter(
view &$view,SearchApiViewsQuery &$query) {

 ...
   }
 }
```

to add missing query conditions like

```
AND field_name = 2015-10-01 (as timestamp)
AND field_name = 2015-10-02
AND field_name = 2015-10-03
```

to take care of all conditions.

I hope this is helpful to someone who is in need of a similar solution.